# Spring Integration TCP factory error handling

Tags: spring, tcp, spring-integration

I would like to handle TCP connection factory exceptions.

With an abstract connection factory:

```
@Bean
public AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientFactory() {
    TcpNetClientConnectionFactory factory = new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory(host, Integer.parseInt(port));
    factory.setSoKeepAlive(Boolean.parseBoolean(keepAlive));
    factory.setSoTimeout(timeout);
    factory.setSoReceiveBufferSize(Integer.parseInt(bufferSize)); 
    factory.setSoSendBufferSize(Integer.parseInt(bufferSize));   
    return factory;
}
```

This connection is injected in both TcpSendingMessageHandler and TcpReceivingChannelAdapter separated beans.

```
@Bean
public TcpReceivingChannelAdapter tcpIn() {
...
receiver.setConnectionFactory(clientFactory());
...
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(...)
public TcpSendingMessageHandler tcpOut() {
...
sender.setConnectionFactory(clientFactory());
...
}
```

I have some ApplicatioListeners such as: TcpConnectionExceptionEvent, TcpConnectionCloseEvent and TcpConnectionOpenEvent.

```
@EventListener
public void handleTcpConnectionCloseEvent(TcpConnectionExceptionEvent event){
...
}
```

However, I detected when an opened connection was closed, a TcpConnectionExceptionEvent was launched but not when the connection was not even opened. How it is possible to deal with `“connection refused”` problems or any other TCP errors?

Is it possible to start/stop the connection using the control bus? I am sending:

```
Message operation = MessageBuilder.withPayload("@clientFactory.isRunning()").build();
boolean sent = operationChannel.send(operation);
```

This seems to be not working because no response was received and only creates “continuous” calls looking for the reference swamping the application. `clientFactory` beans exists (checked with `context.getBeanDefinitionNames()`)

Additionally, could I set a max retries for trying to reconnect?

**Edit (Retry Advice):** I added the tcpRetryAdvice to my tcp outbound channel but I am still confused because the `clientFactory()` (when `“connection refused”`) does not follow the defined policy in the retryAdvice. How can I control the current attemps and if finally the message was delivered?

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "tcpSender", adviceChain = "tcpRetryAdvice")
public TcpSendingMessageHandler tcpOut(AbstractClientConnectionFactory connectionFactory) { ... }

@Bean
public RequestHandlerRetryAdvice tcpRetryAdvice() {

SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
    retryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(2);

ExponentialBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new ExponentialBackOffPolicy();
    backOffPolicy.setInitialInterval(3000);
    backOffPolicy.setMaxInterval(10000);
    backOffPolicy.setMultiplier(2);

RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();      
    retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
    retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);

RequestHandlerRetryAdvice tcpRetryAdvice = new RequestHandlerRetryAdvice();
    tcpRetryAdvice.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate);

    // This allows fail-controlling
    tcpRetryAdvice.setRecoveryCallback(new ErrorMessageSendingRecoverer(failMessageChannel()));

    return tcpRetryAdvice;
}
```

**Edit (ControlBus):**

I am just trying to stop sending messages to TCP because I have to know when the TCP (connectionFactory) is connected in order to do not drop away JMS consumed messages.

**Edit (Logging error for beans)**

First of all, I have:

```
tcpRetryAdvice.setRecoveryCallback(new ErrorMessageSendingRecoverer(failMessageChannel()));
```

This is OK to trace the exception but how I could get the message not sent?

Then I have error sent to the `errorChannel` but I am still seeing the whole stacktrace when the `clientFactory()` bean raises a `"connecton refused"` exception. I would like to avoid this:

```
[ERROR][TcpSendingMessageHandler] - [TcpSendingMessageHandler.java:80] - 26/08/2016
                20:40:57.424 - Error creating connection
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    ....
```

I just want:

```
In my error channel: Message not delivered <Failed to obtain a connection; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect>
```

I am sending the callback to a `failChannel()` and I do not want to see the stacktrace. Ideally, I want to manage the callback. Get the message not sent to save it for waiting the socket reconnection and log the error with an errorChannel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new `TcpConnectionFailedEvent` was [recently added](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4080).

4.3.2 should be released in the next week or so; you can try it out first using the 4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT version.

You can add a [retry advice](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#retry-advice) to the outbound adapter.

I am not sure what you're saying about the control bus.

Comment: `isRunning()` doesn't mean it's connected it just means it's ready to make connections. You need to show how you configured the retry advice on the adapter. The connection factory has a method to list the open connections, but it's not available over the control bus.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something in my configuration, I just have TcpSendingMessageHandler as a sender and the tcpRetryAdvice bean. Both components described in the EDIT1. This is not a gateway, just an outound channel. The service-activator gets the message and sends it thought TCP

Comment: Sorry - missed the `adviceChain` property. Turn on DEBUG logging for org.springframework.retry to observe the retry behavior.

Comment: I have to read more about the retry advice. I am solving my issue with an specific advice callback. it works really well. tcpRetryAdvice.setRecoveryCallback(new ErrorMessageSendingRecoverer(failMessageChannel()));

Comment: I only have one more thing to deal about logging. I am still getting connection refused with its stacktrace on the console. Could I avoid this behaviour sending everything to the error channel?

Comment: I'd have to see the rest of your config to understand the error handling.

Comment: I added the AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientFactory() complete bean and an explanation of what I am looking for the logging and callback.

Comment: The `ErrorMessageSendingRecoverer` sends an `ErrorMessage` which has a `MessagingException` payload with the `failedMessage` and `cause` properties. In order to determine why you are also getting a message sent to the `errorChannel`, I need to see exactly what's upstream of the adapter - you may need to set an `errorChannel` to `nullChannel` to suppress.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121973/discussion-between-crm86-and-gary-russell).